# Tkiz compile error can't solve

Tags: compilation-error

I'm attempting to make a figure in Tkiz but now it gives me this vauge complie timed out error with no indication on what is the cause here's the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds, positioning,arrows,automata,shadows,fit,shapes,intersections,calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,intersections}
\begin{document}
\tracingall
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=stealth,
        donor/.style={shade, ball color=red},
         acceptor/.style={shade, ball color=blue},
        electron/.style={shade, ball color=black},
         vacancy/.style={shade, ball},
        background/.style={ball color=blue!20, opacity=0.4},]
    %Draw the donor atoms
    \foreach \x in {1,1.5,2,3,3.5}
            \draw [donor] (\x,1,-0.5) circle (0.25cm);

    %Draw the acceptor atoms
    \foreach \x in {6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5}
           \draw [acceptor] (\x,0.55,-0.2) circle (0.25cm);


    %Draw the electrons molecules
    \draw [electron] (1.5,3.8) circle (0.15cm);


    %Draw excitation arrows showing the electrons going to the excited state
     \draw (2.5,1) -- (2.5,4.4) [->,thick];
     \draw (7,3.4) -- (7,1) [->,thick];
     \draw (3.5,4.5) -- (6.3,3.5) [->,thick, color=red];

     %draw vacancy
   \shadedraw [vacancy] (2.5,1) circle (0.25cm) 
   node [above=3pt,right=2pt] {\small{2-}};

    %Draw orbital levels
    \draw (1.5,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5) [--,very thick];
    \draw (1.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1.5) [--,very thick];

    \draw (6.3,3.5) -- (8.3,3.5) [--,very thick];
    \draw (6.3,1) -- (8.3,1) [--,very thick];

    %Draw the background
    %\begin{scope}
     %       \clip (1,1) rectangle (8.5,5);
      %      \draw[background] (4.5,1,-0.5) circle (3.5cm);
    %\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `vacancy` style: `ball` -> `ball color=white` and replaced the `--` in the orbital levels to `-` to make it compile. None of the libraries you are loading are needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds, positioning,arrows,automata,shadows,fit,shapes,intersections,calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,intersections}
\begin{document}
%\tracingall
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=stealth,
        donor/.style={shade, ball color=red},
         acceptor/.style={shade, ball color=blue},
        electron/.style={shade, ball color=black},
         vacancy/.style={shade, ball color=white},
        background/.style={ball color=blue!20, opacity=0.4},]
    %Draw the donor atoms
    \foreach \x in {1,1.5,2,3,3.5}
            \draw [donor] (\x,1,-0.5) circle (0.25cm);

    %Draw the acceptor atoms
    \foreach \x in {6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5}
           \draw [acceptor] (\x,0.55,-0.2) circle (0.25cm);


    %Draw the electrons molecules
    \draw [electron] (1.5,3.8) circle (0.15cm);


    %Draw excitation arrows showing the electrons going to the excited state
     \draw (2.5,1) -- (2.5,4.4) [->,thick];
     \draw (7,3.4) -- (7,1) [->,thick];
     \draw (3.5,4.5) -- (6.3,3.5) [->,thick, color=red];

     %draw vacancy
   \shadedraw [vacancy] (2.5,1) circle (0.25cm) 
   node [above=3pt,right=2pt] {\small{2-}};

    %Draw orbital levels
    \draw (1.5,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5) [-,very thick];
    \draw (1.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1.5) [-,very thick];

    \draw (6.3,3.5) -- (8.3,3.5) [-,very thick];
    \draw (6.3,1) -- (8.3,1) [-,very thick];

    %Draw the background
    %\begin{scope}
     %       \clip (1,1) rectangle (8.5,5);
      %      \draw[background] (4.5,1,-0.5) circle (3.5cm);
    %\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also do not understand why you are switching back and forth between 3d and 2d coordinates. This is an attempt to somewhat unify the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds, positioning,arrows,automata,shadows,fit,shapes,intersections,calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,intersections}
\begin{document}
%\tracingall
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=stealth,
        donor/.style={shade, ball color=red},
         acceptor/.style={shade, ball color=blue},
        electron/.style={shade, ball color=black},
         vacancy/.style={shade, ball color=white, opacity=0.4},
        background/.style={ball color=blue!20, opacity=0.4},]
    %Draw the donor atoms
    \foreach \x in {1,1.5,2,3,3.5}
            \draw [donor] (\x,1,-0.5) circle (0.25cm);

    %Draw the acceptor atoms
    \foreach \x in {6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5}
           \draw [acceptor] (\x,0.55,-0.2) circle (0.25cm);


    %Draw the electrons molecules
    \draw [electron] (2.5,4.55,-0.5) circle (0.15cm);


    %Draw excitation arrows showing the electrons going to the excited state
     \draw (2.5,1,-0.5) -- (2.5,4.4,-0.5) [->,thick];
     \draw (7,3.4) -- (7,1) [->,thick];
     \draw (3.5,4.5) -- (6.3,3.5) [->,thick, color=red];

     %draw vacancy
   \shade[vacancy] (2.5,1,-0.5) circle (0.25cm) 
   node [above=3pt,right=2pt,font=\small] {2-};

    %Draw orbital levels
    \draw (1.5,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5) [-,very thick];
    \draw (1.5,1.5) -- (3.5,1.5) [-,very thick];

    \draw (6.3,3.5) -- (8.3,3.5) [-,very thick];
    \draw (6.3,1) -- (8.3,1) [-,very thick];

    %Draw the background
    %\begin{scope}
     %       \clip (1,1) rectangle (8.5,5);
      %      \draw[background] (4.5,1,-0.5) circle (3.5cm);
    %\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you well, i'm still pretty new to latex and was attempting to adapt someone else's template to fit what I Needed

Comment: @ElderMoose You're welcome! BTW, if this answer solved your problem, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it?